# The system cannot find the file specified classes

Tags: asp.net

My website is working offline, but online it gives me the follwing error.  We already worked around SQL, because it could be DB-problem, there is a reference to a class, and this class is to get to the database.  It's this exercise: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-with-221c01f5#content

**The system cannot find the file specified
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace: 
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]**
   **

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) +821
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +332
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +699
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +89
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +191
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +90
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +217    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection
>   t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +360
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()
>   +426    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +10
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +189
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation) +78
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +175
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +556
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String
>   createDatabaseScript) +86
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) +164
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) +76
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +134
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection
>   connection) +119
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +142
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration) +78
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext
>   internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
>   +89    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext
>   objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState) +218
>
>   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context) +151
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
>   +76    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action) +60
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>   +357    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext
>   c) +7
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
>   +110    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
>   action) +198
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>   +73    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +28
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   +52    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewPagedDataSource.GetEnumerator() +291
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateItemsWithoutGroups(ListViewPagedDataSource
>   dataSource, Boolean dataBinding, InsertItemPosition insertPosition,
>   ArrayList keyArray) +209
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +1032
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data) +35
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data) +128
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +34
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +80
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() +102
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls() +52
>   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +92
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +883

**

This is the code what could be a problem, because the website is working, without this code.

```
            <asp:ListView ID="categoryList"  
            ItemType="MyToysHome.Models.Category" 
            runat="server"
            SelectMethod="GetCategories" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <b style="font-size: large; font-style: normal">

            <a href="~/ProductList.aspx?id=<%#: Item.CategoryID %>">
            <%#: Item.CategoryName %></a>
                </a>
                </b>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemSeparatorTemplate>  |  </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: I don't see how the `c` tag is fitting here.

Comment: oh ok.  there are a lot of c# classes bound to the page: Models, Category, Products...

Comment: Your error message says `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)`. Have you verified that everything is installed and running?

Comment: I tried logging in with the login-script, that works fine.  database connection works properly.  I also see that I was logged in in MSSQL.

Comment: Besides that I also tried a connection with SqlDataSource, and that works fine too, with a GridView.